# Generic Class Return by a provider?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am sure there is a way to return a `dynamic` or `generic` instance of a class from a riverpod FutureProvider?

I can fetch different tracker data from an API. It can be for Physical Activity or Weight data for instance. So far, I tried this but does not work, not even compile:

```dart
final trackerDataProvider = FutureProvider.family<AbstractTrackerData, TrackerType>((ref, trackerType) async {
  final repository = ref.read(trackerRepositoryProvider);
  AbstractTrackerData trackerData =
      await repository.getTrackerData(trackerType);
  return trackerData;
});
```

and in my Widget

```dart
class PhysicalActivityLandingTrackerScreen extends HookWidget {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final trackerData = useProvider(trackerDataProvider(TrackerType.physicalactivity));
    ...
   }
}
```

and my tracker data classes

```dart
class SmokeFree extends AbstractTrackerData {
...
}
class PhysicalActivity extends AbstractTrackerData {
...
}
class Weight extends AbstractTrackerData {
...
}
```

and the enum

```dart
enum TrackerType {
  physicalactivity,
  exercise,
  weeklyweight,
  bloodpressure,
  saltyfoodsubstitution,
  goodfatsubstitution,
  medicationuse,
  smokefree
}
```

Comment: If you're asking if generics are possible with riverpod then no, that is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  because Generic methods have a type parameter (the diamond operator enclosing the type) before the return type of the method declaration. ... Generic methods can have different type parameters separated by commas in the method signature. Method body for a generic method is just like a normal method.
Hence we can say that it is returned by provider.

Comment: the code I shared above does not work. How would you proceed then?